# Handling misplaced data when cleaning empty values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a project where I need to extract data from a PDF table and convert it into a pandas dataframe. The original table looks like this.

```
   C100    C200    C300
    30      0       92
    22      0       6
    46      0       2
```

However, I've encountered a problem where the output results are not what I expected. Specifically, in the resulting dataframe, the C200 column has misplaced values

```
    0       1       2     3
0   C100    C200          C300
1   30              0     92
2   22              0     6
3   46              0     2
```

My attempt has been to first convert the empty values to NaN and then remove them, but the issue is that I end up replacing them with incorrect values that do not correspond to the original table:

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

    0       1       2     3
0   C100    C200    NaN   C300
1   30      NaN     0     92
2   22      NaN     0     6
3   46      NaN     0     2


df.ffill(axis=1)

    0       1       2     3
0   C100    C200    C200  C300
1   30      30      0     92
2   22      22      0     6
3   46      46      0     2
```

I'm wondering if someone could suggest a way to replace these NaN values with the original values from the table?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Most likely, you need to find out the reason for such a column shift and resolve it, and not fix the corrupted data.

Answer (score 1):

I think general solution is problematic, here is necessary use:

```
df.iloc[0, 2] = df.iloc[0, 1]

df = df.drop([1], axis=1)

df = df.iloc[1:].set_axis(df.iloc[0].tolist(), axis=1)
print (df)
  C100 C200 C300
1   30  0.0   92
2   22  0.0    6
3   46  0.0    2
```